# Access Denied when loading URL in JavaFX WebView (ui4j)

Tags: java, javafx, webview, webkit, ui4j

I am using a JavaFX WebView (with ui4j library) to load a website. But I get this error in one of the urls that I am loading..

```
Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "{url}" on this server.
Reference #18.9d086a7c.1518661853.652b53a
```

It works on normal browsers. e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari. But with my java browser it doesn't.

Now I am aware that this is some sort of an [apache-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/) but I want to have a work around on this since I don't have control over this website.

Additionally I have a custom SSL verification to check on whitelisted issuers. I also tried previously to disable the [SSLVerification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724901/disable-sslhandshakeexception-for-a-single-connection/37861267#answer-37861267).

But to no luck, the issue still persists.

Comment: If the server denies you access, it denies you access. You can't work around that with client side code.

Comment: Well basically it works on normal browsers. e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari. But with my java browser it doesn't. So somehow I was thinking that there is some possible workaround for this.

Comment: OK: maybe you could mention that in the question? As your question stands, all you are asking is how you can get access to a site that denies you access, which is not a problem that has a general solution (for obvious reasons). If all you want to do is make a web site think that `WebView` is a different browser than the one it is, you just need to set the user agent header in the request. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292054/detect-javafx-webview

Comment: I am setting the userAgent to chrome's "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36". And the issue still persists.